# Disable widgets for Windows 11 kiosk

Tags: windows-11, kiosk, widgets

I've set up a Windows 11 kiosk using Edge and a full screen web application.

This works pretty decently.  However, the "widgets" panel is still accessible by swiping from the left hand of the screen to the right.  When a user does this, the "sign in to use your widgets" screen pops up.

How do I disable this?

[image: "Sign in to use your widgets"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from PowerShell as administrator run:

```
winget uninstall "windows web experience pack"
```